# iCal with Google CalDAV issues

Tags: mail.app, ical, gmail, calendar, google-calendar

I currently have iCal syncing to one Google account with 1 main calendar and 3 sub-calendars (selected on Delegation tab). Let's say that this account is `example@gmail.com`.

This is the only one account set up in iCal.

Additionally I have 4 email accounts defined in Mail.app in this order:

1. `example1@example.com`
2. `example2@example.com`
3. `example@gmail.com`
4. `example3@example.com`

---

#### Problem 1 - iCal will not send out invites to attendees

I cannot make iCal send invites when creating an event within a calendar that's synced with Google.

I have to create a local calendar on Mac, create an event there - invites are sent out "correctly" (see Problem 2), then I simply move the event from one calendar to another and this seems to do the trick.

This seems to be a bit troublesome though (obviously, really). Is there anything I can do to make it work properly - so the invites are sent out from Google's CalDAV calendar?

---

#### Problem 2 - iCal invites email addresses

iCal seems to be totally inconsistent with using email addresses when sending invitations.

Consider the setup:

- 1 CalDAV account in iCal (`example@gmail.com`),
- 1 local calendar (as mentioned in Problem 1),
- 4 email accounts in Mail (as described above).

Now iCal seems to be sending invites using the topmost email account set up in Mail.app - in this case `example1@example.com`. Is there a way to use different email account to do this?

Also, it seems that iCal creates invites using the email account defined in iCal accounts - in this case `example@gmail.com`, even though I use local Calendar and not the CalDAV one!

This means that invite is sent from `example1@example.com`, but people replying to invites send them back to `example@gmail.com`. This really is plain wrong. Any way to sort it out?

**NOTE**: Ideally I'd like iCal to send invites from the second Mail account - `example2@example.com`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iCal doesn't send invitations - Google Calendar do.

You need to set up Notifications for each Google Calendar - main and sub-calendars.

```
"Google Cal->Calendar settings->Calendars->[select calendar]->Notifications->[set check mark at Email and/or SMS for each type of invitations]"
```

Answer (score -2):

Someone needs to read the help files on google's page... Just because you've sync'd your google cal w/ ical doesn't mean you can go & send invites to anyone willy nilly. Have you told google that your going to "share" your cal w/ this other person who may or may not have a google account? Did they accept your ical share? As far as "sending out" invites, that'll happen off your "default" email account. Generally iCal will send out a "link" to your event & lots of people just click on that to go to a page where they "accept" or "deny" or "reply" to your invite, so auto received from your gmail account. You could set up a rule to forward them to your other email account if you prefer?